# Hovering issue Jquery library

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have an issue about hover function . I have an example : `<a href="http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/YeBMA/1/">Click here  </a>`

```js
$('.curtain').hover(function() {
  var $container = $(this).closest('div.container');
  $container.find('.containerLeft').addClass('lefthover');
  $container.find('.containerRight').addClass('righthover');
}, function() {
  var $container = $(this).closest('div.container');
  $container.find('.containerLeft').removeClass('lefthover');
  $container.find('.containerRight').removeClass('righthover');
});
```

```css
.lefthover {
  border: 2px solid green;
}
.righthover {
  border: 2px solid orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <img class="curtain containerLeft" src="http://example.com/containerleft.jpg" />
  <img class="curtain containerRight" src="http://example.com/containerright.jpg" />
</div>
<div class="container">
  <img class="curtain containerLeft" src="http://example.com/containerleft.jpg" />
  <img class="curtain containerRight" src="http://example.com/containerright.jpg" />
</div>
<div class="container">
  <img class="curtain containerLeft" src="http://example.com/containerleft.jpg" />
  <img class="curtain containerRight" src="http://example.com/containerright.jpg" />
</div>
```

I hover over an image and I want  to add a class and then remove it, but the class is automatically added several times, instead.

Can you please help?

Comment: what do you mean by `automatically added several times`?

Comment: jQuery doesn't add same class to DOM multiple times. I think 2px widthed border causes mouseenter and mouseleave runs multiple times, because effect area expanded.

Comment: look at this behavior , when I hover the building http://metroffice.gd.ro/ro/floorplans/

Comment: $("#image-maps-metroffice area").each(function () {
                var idFloor = $(this).attr('href').substring(0, 2);
                $(this).mouseover(function () {
                      $("#floor" + idFloor).addClass('hoverfl');
                }).mouseout(function () {
                    $("#floor" + idFloor).removeClass('hoverfl');
                });
            });

Answer (score 0):

Replace your jQuery code with this one and check

```
$('.curtain').hover(function() {
  var $container = $(this).parent('.container');
  $container.children('.containerLeft').addClass('lefthover');
  $container.children('.containerRight').addClass('righthover');
}, function() {
  var $container = $(this).parent('div.container');
  $container.children('.containerLeft').removeClass('lefthover');
  $container.children('.containerRight').removeClass('righthover');
});
```

I hope you will get the answer, you can check it on [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/basilpjoy/cf5c901m/1/)

Answer (score 0):

The reason why this is happening is b/c the hover function fires so quickly, primarily when using `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`, which is what makes jquery's `hover` function.

I've always used this plugin, called **hoverIntent**. You can find it [here](http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html). Basically what this plugin does is calculates pixels (from when your mouse moves into the "area", and if it moves out of the area within an amount of time). These calculations will stop the event (hover) from firing so many times, and only fire it when the user is actually hovering for a pre-determined amount of time (dependent on the options you pass in). All these options you can change and pass into the init of the plugin.

This has been out for years, and has saved me plenty of times. I highly recommend it.

Here's the example if you were to use hoverIntent:

```
$('.container').hoverIntent({
    selector: '.curtain',   // this is the same as using jquery's `on` event
    sensitivity: 2,  // or w/e number - read docs
    interval: 50, // default is 100
    over: function () {
       var $container = $(this).closest('div.container');
       $container.find('.containerLeft').addClass('lefthover');
       $container.find('.containerRight').addClass('righthover');
    },
    out: function() {
      var $container = $(this).closest('div.container');
      $container.find('.containerLeft').removeClass('lefthover');
      $container.find('.containerRight').removeClass('righthover');
    }
});
```